# Leave ACL handling to Windows with Cygwin rsync

Tags: windows, cygwin, rsync, acl

I'm running an `rsync` command, copying my files from a server to my Windows machine like:

```
rsync -rt --partial-dir=".rsync" --del rsync://server/a/ a/
```

Whenever this command creates a directory, it tends to create a directory with crazy ACLs/permissions.  For me, it tends to create ten `<not inherited>` entries, with one deny entry for the user who ran the `rsync` command, and the others not making much sense, either.  This even happens using the `--chmod=ugo=rwX` option, which a [similar thread](https://superuser.com/questions/69620/rsync-file-permissions-on-windows) suggested.

What can I do to prevent `rsync` from trying to set permissions at all (and just leave the permissions to the ACL inheritance in Windows)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mount the directory in question with the `noacl` option, as described [in the manual](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table).

(And if you want to know why the mapping of Unix permissions to Windows ACLs is not straightforward, [see here](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-files).)

Comment: `noacl` does prevent the crazy permissions, but since it fakes permissions with the "readonly" bit, I get a bunch of weird partial read-only directories. This is an improvement.

Comment: How about rsync's `--no-perms` option?

Comment: Actually, it looks like I get that "partial readonly" symptom on any directory (whether `rsync` created it or not). It appears [Windows is saying](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-files/read-only-green-square/8706deea-bfa4-41c0-89ae-35c72ec873c2) just that [directories have no readonly property](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/winxp/t1065875615).

Comment: ak2's answer was very helpful to be, but it took quite a bit of googling to find how to setup the `noacl` in /etc/fstab properly. I found this [link quite](http://i-cat.blogspot.com/2010/01/cygwinnontsec-in-cygwin-17-speak.html) helpful. Using `noacl` fixed my rsync problems - thanks.

Comment: @miking already gave a nice hint with that link and the `noacl` option. Didn't work out for me with MobaXterm (portable), as that seems to re-create `/etc/fstab` on each start. I partially got around that placing `mount -c /drives -o binary,posix=0,user,auto,noacl` into my `.bashrc`. "Partially" as this only affects the "Windows drive letters" (and not e.g. `/home`).

Comment: Would be great if someone knew how to do this with cwrsync (or any standalone `rsync.exe` that doesn't use the full cygwin).

Comment: @SimonEast - Any luck with finding what options to make this work with CwRSync?

Comment: @AlexS I never got it working reliably. rsync would work 90% of the time but I still often ended up with some read-only files that needed their permissions reset periodically. Pain in the butt. 

Comment: @SimonEast - Found this while you replied. Could you try this & respond? - https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/02/07/windows-rsync-jboss-developer-studio/ - # If you distribution doesn’t have an fstab file, which is typical for `cwRsync`, that is easily fixed. Ccreate the file at `$MY_RSYNC_DIST_DIR/etc/fstab` and paste the following content:
`none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user,noacl 0 0`

Comment: Just adding that this still works at the end of 2020 -- and, as someone somewhere noted -- I had to kill all of the existing cygwin sessions to get the fstab table to get reloaded.